# Are this two routes same in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

Routes in Express:

```
/search/:company-name
/search/:category-name
```

I can see that first one is fired for both requests so they are same, but is there a way to solve this without involving for example:

```
/search/company/:company-name
/search/category/:category-name
```

Comment: How would node.js/express differentiate a company name from a category name at the routing level?

Comment: @DrakaSAN that is my question.

Comment: Drown beaten me in speed for the long version, but my first comment was rethorical. You can separate company and category once you know what it is, but express can t do it for you.

Comment: You can use [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) (how Express parses routes) directly to inspect what pattern that will be used to match requests. For both, the result will be the same – `/^\/search\/([^\/]+?)\/?$/i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.

The router just see a route that starts with `search/` and ends with a wildcard. The only thing that change is the name you give to that wildcard, which doesn't matter for the router, it's still the same URL.

You can solve this by either changing the route, or you can parse the route argument (the wildcard) and do something different depending on its value.

Comment: Yes, that what I was thinking as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a query instead of a param.
Your urls would be:

```
/search?company=company-name
/search?category=category-name
```

Your route is `/search` and you use req.query instead of req.params.

It's either that,

- or your solution of changing the route,
- or somehow parsing the parameter to decide whether it's a company or a category
- or changing your route to a post and using key-value pairs in the post body